# How to avoid NullPointerException when re-back to FragmentActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My `STACK_TRACE` when I came back to FragmentActivity from another activity.
I searched lot for how to solve this, and I found a clue that I need to save state of fragment.
But in that clue article said, when I use FragmentPagerAdapter, I do not need to save state.

So, I confussed. Am I use FragmentPagerAdapter correctly?

Please Help me...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test20140320/com.example.test20140320.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.test20140320.MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.<init>(MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.java:98)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
   at com.example.test20140320.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
   ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.test20140320.MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.<init>(MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.java:98)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
   at com.example.test20140320.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at com.example.test20140320.MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.<init>(MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02.java:98)
```

My code:

```
public MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02()
    {
        super();
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); //This is line 98
        tab2 = this;
    }
```

I think the cause is at `savedInstanceState`, but don't know how, and how, and how....

Below is what i use `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
I think this is the most doubtful part.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) 
        {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.


            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                Fragment fragment_tab1 = new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab1.setRetainInstance(true);

                return fragment_tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment fragment_tab2 = new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_01(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab2.setRetainInstance(true);
                return fragment_tab2;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragment_tab3 =  new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_03(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab3.setRetainInstance(true);
                return fragment_tab3;

            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is this code leaky??
Am I use FragmentPagerAdapter correctly? OTL....
How can I fix it....?
Please Help me!

P.S. First create fragmentActivity is successful.

Comment: I had this issue quite a few times. Its kind of a race condition. Just check if(getActivity != null) {} before using getActivity() method. It should be fine after that. The reason is unknown to me but it worked in most of the cases for me. Otherwise you can debug the code and see what is exactly null.

Comment: Few more things - you should not be using getActivity() in fragment constructor because this method will return null till the time onActivityCreated() gets called. Hope it will help

Comment: @Varundroid Thx for Comment! I notice that fragment costructor is not safety from getActivity(), but when I call getActivity() at override onStart() method, It just return null too.

Comment: Just put an if(getActivity != null) and it should just work. It is happening because fragment didn't get attach back to the activity by the getActivity() gets called.

Comment: @Varundroid Thx again, but 'if(getActivity)' didn't solve anything as a result... I can't use ApplicationContext. that means fail to me.

Comment: Which means you need to structure your code better. Very first thing why you need an Application Context. There is better way of doing things than making things Global to whole application. It would be great if you can explain What your exactly you are trying to achieve by using getApplicationContext() when you can use getActivity() directly anywhere you need mContext.

Comment: In simple words you can replace mContext with getActivity() wherever you need.

Comment: @Varundroid umm... ye Thx so much Varundroid, but my question means I don't care that getActivity() or getActivity().getApplicationContext() or mContext.
I can use just getActivity() everywhere, but when I call getActivity() anywhere at my code, It return null when not first time, just second time that I came back from another activity.
 I think my english is not so good enough to explain my think. 
Thanks again for answer. Varundroid

Comment: in "new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02(getApplicationContext())" you are passing application context and your posted a no argument constructor. Does that constructor getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

to `onAttached` or `onActivityCreated`

Comment: I tested at onStart(), onAttached(), onActivityCreated(), but all failed. getActivity() return null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your activity is crashing some where else and hence you are not able to get activity reference in your fragment class. Go through the stack trace, the entire log, somewhere prior to the log that you have posted here, will be some other exception that is causing the activity to stop.

In order to use activity reference in the fragment class create on `mActivity` variable in your fragment and before using it check for NP `if(mActivity!=null)`. Initialize `mActivity` in `onAttached` method of fragment class

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}
```